# Using .addEventListener for all values of array at once

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, loops, addeventlistener

I'm trying to use .addEventListener inside a loop with arrays (if that's at all possible) for use with multiple audio players on the same webpage. The audio players are just standard HTML5 audio but with custom controls.

This is just some test code to explain:

```
array[0].addEventListener('click',function() {
    array[0].play();
});

array[1].addEventListener('click',function() {
    array[1].play();
});
```

How would I be able to condense rather than writing this out for every value of the array? I've already tried putting it inside a (for) loop but then it just appeared to ignore it altogether:

```
For (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].addEventListener('click',function() {
        array[i].play();
    });
}
```

Apologies in advance if I'm being an idiot and/or missing something obvious.

Comment: for loop would be a correct way to do it, however, you have a scope problem. Every click handler bound within the loop will call .play() on the last item in the array.

Comment: you should try using closures..

Comment: No problem. I rolled back your edit because it isn't relevant to the question, please keep comments in the... comments section. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code

```
for( var i=0; i<array.length; i++ )
{
    (function(index)    // keep i pointing to right index
    {
        array[index].addEventListener('click', function ()
        {
            array[index].play();
        }, false);
    })(i)

}
```

PS: I am no ninja in closures so if it doesn't work. Apologies

Comment: don't `return`, it exits the loop on the first iteration. You are somewhat close though, you need to remove the return, turn the function declaration into a function expression, then execute it. `(function(i){...})(i)`

Comment: something like that? @KevinB

Comment: Yes, but your first `(` is backwards, and you need to use `index` inside, not `i`. and... `play` isn't defined, that needs to be an anonymous function

Comment: edit it for me please..@KevinB